# Diplay loading indicator for FullCalendar and Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

is there a way to display a loading indicator on FullCalendar 5 and VueJS ?
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/loading
I checked the documentation and it states it works via AJAX request, but don't say anything about other technologies.

Is there any way to have something similar and easy to implement ?
Regards.

When i get my agendas entries, i update my calendars with the events.

```
entreesAgenda() {
      // Ajout des evenements dans le(s) calendrier(s)
      let entrees = []
      if (this.entreesAgenda) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.utilisateurs.length; i++) {
          entrees = this.data.items.filter(
            (f) => f.idPersonnel === this.utilisateurs[i].id
          )
          // Mise à jour des businessHours
          this.$refs.utilisateur[i]
            .getApi()
            .setOption('businessHours', this.calculBusinessHours(entrees))

          // Insertion des entrees d'agenda dans le calendrier
          for (let m = 0; m < entrees.length; m++) {
            this.$refs.utilisateur[i].getApi().addEvent(entrees[m])
          }
        }
      }
      this.updateView()
    },
```

But i don't know how to use the loading.

Comment: It works when loading events via AJAX yes. That should really be the only time when loading of events might be slow enough to need it...why, what other technologies / scenarios are you thinking of where you've got an issue with slow loading times?

Comment: Retrieving events for one month for one person, or one month for multiple people.

Comment: Ok. Well how are you retrieving that information? If you're fetching it from an API then it will use AJAX, so the loading indicator would work. If you're fetching it from local data in the browser then it should be so fast you don't need the loading indicator. You haven't really explained exactly what the problem is. I asked you about what other technologies you're thinking of but you didn't mention any.

Comment: Sorry. Indeed i fetch datas from an API.

Comment: Ok. So yes you can use the loading indicator then.

Comment: I updated my original post with the code where i update the calendars, can you provide me an exemple ? I don't understand how to use the loading. Thanks

Comment: You appear to be adding events to the calendar individually via addEvent. That's not efficient. Create an event feed as per the fullCalendar documentation - there are two alternative approaches, see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function. Then you can use the loading indicator.